# How to prove second moment of a multivariate normal distribution is finite?

Tags: statistics

recently I'm dealing with prove $E|W_i|^2<\infty$, where $W_i$ follows a multivariate normal distribution, could anyone provide some references on this topic? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) or at [Isserlis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem) can help.

Comment: If $W_i$ has a multivariate normal distribution, then $\operatorname{E} \left| W_i\right|^2$ is a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: What does the subscript index $i$ mean?